# Improve Efficiency for This Text Processing Code

Tags: c#, text

I am writing a program that counts the number of words in a text file which is already in lowercase and separated by spaces. I want to use a dictionary and only count the word IF it's within the dictionary. The problem is the dictionary is quite large (~100,000 words) and each text document has also ~50,000 words. As such, the codes that I wrote below gets very slow (takes about 15 sec to process one document on a quad i7 machine). I'm wondering if there's something wrong with my coding and if the efficiency of the program can be improved. Thanks so much for your help. Code below:

```
public static string WordCount(string countInput)
        {
            string[] keywords = ReadDic(); /* read dictionary txt file*/

            /*then reads the main text file*/
            Dictionary<string, int> dict = ReadFile(countInput).Split(' ')
                .Select(c => c)
                .Where(c => keywords.Contains(c))
                .GroupBy(c => c)
                .Select(g => new { word = g.Key, count = g.Count() })
                .OrderBy(g => g.word)
                .ToDictionary(d => d.word, d => d.count);

            int s = dict.Sum(e => e.Value);
            string k = s.ToString();
            return k;

        }
```

Comment: Why are you making a dictionary?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can vastly improve performance by reading the text file one line at a time instead of building an enormous string.

You can call

```
File.ReadLines(path).SelectMany(s => s.Split(' '))
```

Do not call `ReadAllLines`; it will need to build an enormous array.

---

Your first `Select` call is *utterly* useless.

---

Your `Contains` call will loop through the entire dictionary for each word in the file.
Thus, the `Where` call is an O(n<sup>2</sup>) operation.

Change `keywords` to a `HashSet<string>`.
Since HashSets can be searched in constant time, the `Where` call will become an O(n) operation, which is much better.

---

Your second `Select` call can be combined with the `GroupBy`, which will cut a large number of object allocations:

```
 .GroupBy(c => c, (word, set) => new { word, count = set.Count() })
```

---

Dictionaries are intrisically unordered, so your `OrderBy` call is a useless waste of time.

Comment: A description of why this speeds things up would get a +1 from me.

Comment: Gotta love linq, makes it nice and easy to add in those O(n)'s

Comment: @SLaks, thanks and for emphasis, none of the changes except the HashSet change will make much difference for large `n`.

Comment: @johnv, to get a `HashSet`, the simplest rewrite is for the line of code to be `HashSet<string> keywords = new HashSet<string>(ReadDic());` You could also refactor the `ReadDic` function itself.

Comment: @Anthony: And change `ReadDic` to return an `IEnumerable<string>` without allocating an array.  (Or, better yet, return a `HashSet<string>` directly)

Comment: @SLaks Where is EnumerateLines? I know ReadLines is avail in .NET 4.0 which allows enumeration before the entire collection is returned but not familiar with EnumerateLines.

Comment: @Aaron: **EDIT**: Sorry; I meant `ReadLines`.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see all your code can be replaced with

```
return ReadFile(countInput).Split(' ').Count(c => keywords.Contains(c));
```

And, as *SLaks* said, HashSet - would improve performance.
One more improvement: if you call this code in loop, the you shouldn't read `ReadDic()` on each iteration - load it once and pass as a parameter.

Comment: He wants a per-word dictionary.

Comment: @SLaks In code given, he returns count of words and doesn't use (returns) dictionary at all. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're running quad-core, you could at least throw in an `AsParallel()` in there.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `string[] keywords` to a `HashSet<string> keywords`.  Your call to "Contains" is essentially a loop, which is going to be vastly slower than a lookup by hash key.

If you want to get REALLY fancy, you could make use of multiple threads by using some [PLINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx), but I would make sure you've optimized your single thread performance before going that route.